# POST REFUND returned error 400 since Feb ~10th

Tags: square-connect

I have a script processing some refund payments that does not work anymore since approx. Feb 10th. Server responds Content-Type is not supported ... even if my header Content-Type looks actually correct

Same code worked before that date which makes me believe something was changed on the server side but I haven't notice anything in the square-connect API changelog recently that would explain this problem.

Any help would be much appreciated :)
Thanks

See below JSON request and response.

```
{"method":"POST",
  "headers":
    {"Authorization":"Bearer [mypersonalid]",
     "Accept":"application/json",
     "Content-Type":"application/json"},
     "payload":
       {"payment_id":"[paymentid]",
        "type":"FULL",
        "reason":"reason"
       }
    }"
}


{"type":"bad_request",
 "message":"The Content-Type of this request is not supported. 
            Supported     type(s): application/json"
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a Square customer support portal. Please contact Square directly.

Comment: Thanks for your question. Which language/platform are you using to send requests to the Connect API?

Comment: @StephenBarlow Javascript/Google App Script. I'm using the method UrlFetchApp.fetch to post which takes the url and parameters I've described. Since I use the personal token id URL is https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/refunds

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please see Troy's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Google App Script, it looks like you have to set the Content-Type header using the special `contentType` parameter ([docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))). That way, Google Apps Script knows to serialize the payload as JSON rather than multipart form data. If you just specify it as a header, Google will override it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot your comments. It's solved!

I've added the contentType in the params and it did not worked but I started to get a new error saying 'bad json object'. Si, I just searched for that and found that the actual encoding of the 'payload' object needed to be "stringify". See answer from user1021710 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18851043/4615977 ("Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp with JSON Payload")

So in this case, contentType was necessary then encoding of the payload too. Google changed their own API around mid-Feb apparently, because code was the same and worked.

Thanks folks !!!

Sample basic code to POST refund request using google app script:

```
var headers = {
  "Authorization" : autorization,
  "Accept": 'application/json',
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

var payload = {
   "payment_id" : paymentid,
   "type" : type,  
   "reason" : reason,
};

var params = {
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "headers" : headers,
  "method" : "post",
  "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
};

var url = "https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/refunds";
paymentsFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```