# How to query from an online database in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, rhino

I am trying to use google apps scripts and google sheets to basically automatically update a google sheet with statistical information every time an NHL team plays.  How do I query nhl.com online database within the Google Apps Scripts environment?  For example -- a stat that I am interested in is total points for a certain team.  How would I get that integer value from nhl.com in Google Apps Scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) that is the GAS's service to send http requests and accept responses.

Your code might look something like:

```
 function getMatchResults() {
    var options = {
        'method': 'get',
        //and any other additional parameters you might need
    };
    var url = 'http://www.nhl.com/stats/team?aggregate=0&gameType=2&report=teamsummary&teamId=24&reportType=season&seasonFrom=20172018&seasonTo=20172018&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points%22'
    var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
    Logger.log(results);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //further on goes your code to actually save the results into your sheet
}
```

If you need this function to run periodically, you'll need to set up a time driven trigger which is described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

UPDATE:
After your comment, there goes the second part.
At first, I assumed that nhl.com has some kind of API that would return responses in JSON format but turns it does not. This is why you were getting the error at JSON.parse — the returned result is not a JSON object but an HTML web page.

So your task gets trickier: you try scraping the page and get the results out of html or use third party APIs like [MySportFeeds](https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/data-feeds/api-docs/). You can also see this [Quora discussion](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-JSON-API-available-for-getting-NHL-information-rosters-lineups-statistics-etc).

If you use MySportFeeds, which seems to be free for personal use, the above function will *probably* look something like:

```
function getMatchResults() {
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'username:password',
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': headers,
    //and any other additional parameters you might need
  };
  var url = 'https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/api/feed/pull/nfl/2016-2017-regular/scoreboard.json?fordate=20161211'
  var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
  Logger.log(results);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //further on goes your code to actually save the results into your sheet
}
```

UPDATE #2:

As per one more comment :) You have 3 options actually:

- scrape the whole page (see [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) about that and [here](http://scraping.pro/scrape-google-app-script/))
- use some third party API (MySportFeeds above)
- look into page source and find where it loads its data from — see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676576/web-scraping-with-google-apps-script#38683584) for more detail.

Using the last option, the code look like:

```
function getMatchResults() {
  var headers = {
    "Origin": "http://http://www.nhl.com/"
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    //and any other additional parameters you might need
  };
  var baseUrl = 'http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/individual/team/basic/game/teamsummary'
  var urlParameters = '?cayenneExp=teamId=23';
  var url = baseUrl + urlParameters;
  var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
  Logger.log(results);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //further on goes your code to actually save the results into your sheet
}
```

You can see here that stats are returned by http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/individual/team/basic/game/teamsummary?cayenneExp= and in the `cayenneExp` parameter you should specify you additional settings (like teamId=23 which is Vancouver in the example). This is how it looks in devtools: http://take.ms/fSH7H

Comment: I am getting an 'unexpected token error' when trying to run the JSON.parse line.  Within the .fetch() parameter, should I put the complete link for the particular value that I want?  For instance, if I wanted total points for the Anaheim Ducks, should I pass: "http://www.nhl.com/stats/team?aggregate=0&gameType=2&report=teamsummary&teamId=24&reportType=season&seasonFrom=20172018&seasonTo=20172018&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points"

Comment: @andrew613 turns it gets trickier than I expected, updated my answer.

Comment: unfortunately i'm still not getting the output i want.  the method is outputting the source code of the page, but i want to extract a particular value from a table in the database.  how would i extract a particular value  such as 'shootout wins' in the table from "http://www.nhl.com/stats/team?aggregate=0&gameType=2&report=teamsummary&teamId=24&reportType=season&seasonFrom=20172018&seasonTo=20172018&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=shootoutGamesWon" for example?

Comment: @andrew613 see Update #2. :)