# Click on button then scrape with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-scraping

I have the to scrape following [URL](https://www.camara.cl/legislacion/ProyectosDeLey/tramitacion.aspx?prmID=14805&prmBOLETIN=14225-13).

It contains an HTML table and when it gets too big then it separates into pages. If I click the link to the next page there is no change in the URL, the new content is just loaded in the website.

Is there a way with Google Apps Script to:

1. click a button with these characteristics
2. wait content to be loaded
3. continue to scrape?

This is what I'm using so far for scraping:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
```

Just in case, this is the DIV containing the paging buttons:

```
<div class="paginacion aleft">
        <span>

        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_pager_rptPager_current_0" class="actual">1</span>
        
        

        
        <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_pager_rptPager_page_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$pager$rptPager$ctl02$page','')">2</a>
        

        
        <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_pager_rptPager_page_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$pager$rptPager$ctl03$page','')">3</a>
```

Comment: Is there a problem with what you are using so far? Cheerio is not a built-in Class so you should add a [mcve]. By the other hand where will you place your button? Are you using the HTML Service or the Card Service for the button?

Comment: I dont have a solution to interact with the button, I have no code for that. I'm not asking for an error i got, I just need to know a way to make google apps script to interact with the website.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38676576/1595451)

Comment: @Rubén cant see a solution in the Possible duplicate. With an extra research, I think I need something with browser capabilities like Selenium or PhantomJS that works in Google Apps Script.

Comment: If you are looking for a software recommendation try [softwarerecs.se] as question asking for them are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I would probably just use a snippet.